# Java interface with parameters as another interface

Tags: java, interface

I have a Java interface like

```
    public interface Filter{
        public boolean acceptData(IFilterData data);
    }

    public interface IFilterData{

    }
```

Why Java is not allowing me to have an implementation class like the below?

```
public class SampleFilterImpl{
    public boolean acceptData(SampleFilterData data){ 
        return true;
    }
}
```

where `SampleFilterData` `implements` `IFilterData`

I'm agreeing to the contract which is specified by the Filter interface right? But what is the logic why it is not allowing me to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I'm agreeing to the contract which is specified by the Filter interface right?

Nope.

The interface lets callers pass *any* implementation of `IFilterData`.

Your class only accepts one specific implementation.

Comment: Hmm... Got it. Then how do we support these use cases in Java?

Comment: @Apps: _What_ use cases? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: The "accept" method tells whether to accept a particular data or,no. In future, there can be a lot of possibilities on the type of data that can be coming to this method. As Mattias mentioned, I can use Generics to support it. But curious to know if there are any other ways to support it.

Comment: No; that would be fundamentally unsafe.  Unless you use generics to make the interface accept only that type, you cannot accept fewer types than the interface method.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant

```
public class SampleFilterImpl implements Filter {
```

because you could have

```
Filter filter = (flag) ? new SampleFilterImpl() : new SomeOtherFilterImpl();
filter.acceptData(new SomeOtherFilterData()); // not SampleFilterData
```

If `flag` was `true` and `filter` referenced an object of type `SampleFilterImpl`, then you'd be passing an argument of type `SomeOtherFilterData` which wouldn't match the parameter type of `SampleFilterData`.

Answer (score 2):

No, you're **not** agreeing to the `Filter` interface. The `Filter` interface specifies that you can give *any* `IFilterData` to a `Filter` instance, meaning that you should be able to do this:

```
public class SomeOtherFilterData implements IFilterData { ... }

new SampleFilterDataImpl().acceptData(new SomeOtherFilterData());
```

However, your `acceptData` only allows for `SampleFilterData` to be passed, which violates the contract.

More general, the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) states that you can only weaken the preconditions and/or strengthen the postconditions of an interface. In Java, this means that you can use sub classes for the return type and the thrown exception types of the overridden method, or throw less exception types.

One solution would be to make your `Filter` generic:

```
public interface Filter<T extends IFilterData> {
    public boolean acceptData(T data);
}
```

and have `SampleFilterImpl` implement `Filter<SampleFilterData>`. Depending on your use case, you might be able to remove `IFilterData` completely and allow `Filter` to be implemented for any `T`.

Comment: Is using Generics the only way by which we can design such scenarios?

Comment: @Apps For statically checkable code, I think it's the only solution.